# Exported Excel File - decimals

Tags: export, excel, precision-and-accuracy

Im trying to export data from the interpolating function result to excel.

everything works fine and the plots are as expected, but if I want to export these data to excel using

```
Export["data.xlsx", Table[Flatten[{t, soldata}], {t, 0, tmax}]]
```

the t values only show 1 decimal whereas the soldata results are expressed in much as 15 decimals. This makes the exported file missing many cells. How can I make t in the excel file export as much decimals.

Here is the last part of the code

`sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqns, init}, vars, {t, 0, 2}, {p}]`

`soldata = Evaluate[sol[100][[1]], sol[100][[2]]]`

`excelData = Table[Flatten[{t, soldata}], {t, 0, 2}]`

`Export["data.xlsx", excelData]`

Comment: Please give a description of `soldata`. Is it a list? Is it a 2-dimensional array where each row is a list of values? If `soldata` is a 2D array, is there a row for each of `0` to `tmax`?

Comment: Maybe `excelData = Table[Flatten[{t, soldata}], {t, 0, 2, 0.001}`

Comment: I still don’t the dimensions and content of `soldata`, but from your edit, I assume `soldata` is a 2D array with 2 columns, and rows for `t = 0`, to `t = tmax`. Do you want column 1 of the Excel data to be values equally spaced between `0` and `tmax`? I’ll assume... I’ve replaced my answer.

Comment: `{t, 0, 2, 0.001}` did the job. I don't know why when I tried this before, It did not work. Its a very simple solution but I missed it. My bad.
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

From the question, I still don't understand what `soldata` is. Can I assume it's a 2D array? If this is wrong, please add the output of `soldata[[1;;2]` to the question.

Assuming `soldata` has 2 columns, and row 1 represents `t = 0`, and the last row represents `t = tmax`. Here are some random values.

```
SeedRandom[123]
(*assume a 2D array, 5 rows by 2 columns*)
soldata = RandomReal[1, {5, 2}];
```

Let's add the time values from `0` to `tmax` as the first column of the Excel data.

```
tmax = 2;
excelData = 
  Prepend[##] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{soldata, N@Subdivide[0, tmax, Length@soldata - 1]}];
```

Or another method,

```
tmax = 2;
elcelData = Flatten /@ 
  Transpose[{N@Subdivide[0, tmax, Length@soldata - 1], soldata}];
```

So `soldata`:

${\small\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.455719 & 0.977826 \\
 0.943215 & 0.962216 \\
 0.302348 & 0.466709 \\
 0.0616383 & 0.385645 \\
 0.429838 & 0.778744 \\
\end{array}
\right)}$

becomes `excelData`:

${\small\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0. & 0.455719 & 0.977826 \\
 0.5 & 0.943215 & 0.962216 \\
 1. & 0.302348 & 0.466709 \\
 1.5 & 0.0616383 & 0.385645 \\
 2. & 0.429838 & 0.778744 \\
\end{array}
\right)}$

Export `excelData` to an Excel spreadsheet.

```
Export["data.xlsx", excelData]
```

Does `excelData` create the correct spreadsheet?

Comment: Maybe I was misunderstood and my question wasn't clear. I edited the question and added an image of what I am missing

Comment: Thank you creidhne for your effort in answering. It was a simple solution and was my bad missing it. I appreciate your answer nonetheless.